# Can you define fields and values with a "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I'm trying to import data into a MySQL table with values not defined in the input file.   I have this php string concatenated query:

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".@mysql_escape_string($this->file_name).
"' IGNORE INTO TABLE `".$this->table_name.
"` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_separate_char).
"' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_enclose_char).
"' ESCAPED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_escape_char).
"' LINES TERMINATED BY '". $this->line_separate_char .
"' ".
($this->use_csv_header ? " IGNORE 1 LINES " : "")
```

Is there a way I can set the account id in this load statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

> The `SET` clause can be used to supply values not derived from the input file. The following statement sets `column3` to the current date and time:
>
> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
>   INTO TABLE t1
>   (column1, column2)
>   SET column3 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

**You can call functions and SQL statements within load data like this:**

```
load data local infile '/tmp/foo.txt' into table foo 
fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n' 
(@col1, @col2) 
set myid=@col1, 
username=CONCAT(@col2, 'abc', 'xyz');
```